# Dynamically select HASH partition in postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql, hash, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

How to write a select query that selects from a parent (partitioned) table, partitioned using HASH partitioning (new in Postgresql 11), that translates to selecting all records from a single partition?

Example: I want this

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
  col1
  .....
) PARTITION BY HASH (col1);

CREATE TABLE child_table_0
PARTITION OF parent_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 15, REMAINDER 0);

[...]

CREATE TABLE child_table_14
PARTITION OF parent_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 15, REMAINDER 14);

-- Query in question
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    *
FROM parent_table
WHERE some_undocumented_hash_expression(col1, 15) = C
```

To return this plan

```
Append  (cost=0.00..67.44 rows=X width=Y)
  ->  Seq Scan on child_table_C  (cost=0.00..67.38 rows=X width=Y)
        Filter: ([?????????]=C)
```

**Alternatives that I know of**

1. List partitioning by expression `PARTITION BY LIST (col1 % 15)`, `... FOR VALUES IN (0)`, selected with `WHERE col1 % 15 = 0`
2. Using an auxiliary column to store (cache) the expression value

Is there a more direct way? I want to get away from `PARTITION BY LIST` when I'm actually partitioning by HASH, but to do this I need a way to select the proper partition without writing dynamic SQL or making it even more complicated than `PARTITION BY LIST (hash_expression)`.

Comment: `where col1 = xxx` will pick the correct partition.

Comment: Yes, but it will not pick the ENTIRE partition, but just a row. The reason I need this is to join 2 large tables on a single key, that happens to be what the tables are partitioned on.

Comment: Related to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483353/postgresql-does-not-use-proper-partition-on-update-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483353/postgresql-does-not-use-proper-partition-on-update-statement)