# PostgreSQL does not use proper partition on UPDATE statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

Executing a regular `UPDATE` statement on a  **partitioned** table seems to be worst than doing it in a regular one.

## Setup

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY HASH (id);

ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE users_p0 PARTITION OF users FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0);
CREATE TABLE users_p1 PARTITION OF users FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 1);
CREATE TABLE users_p2 PARTITION OF users FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 2);

INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES ('1', 'Blue');
INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES ('2', 'Green');
INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES ('3', 'Red');
INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES ('4', 'Yellow');
```

## Query plan for `SELECT` statement

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1';
```

### Result (cost=0.15..2.37)

```
Append  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=76)
  ->  Index Scan using users_p0_pkey on users_p0  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=76)
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = '1'::text)
```

## Query plan for `UPDATE` statement

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE users SET name = 'New blue' WHERE id = '1';
```

### Result (cost=0.15..7.10)

```
Update on users  (cost=0.15..7.10 rows=3 width=82)
  Update on users_p0
  Update on users_p1
  Update on users_p2
  ->  Index Scan using users_p0_pkey on users_p0  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=82)
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = '1'::text)
  ->  Index Scan using users_p1_pkey on users_p1  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=82)
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = '1'::text)
  ->  Index Scan using users_p2_pkey on users_p2  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=82)
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = '1'::text)
```

I expected the query planner to access directly to *users_p0* instead of accessing all partitions

Comment: Does it work if you use  a proper number value instead of comparing a number with a string? `WHERE id = 1;`

Comment: Adding check constraint helps skipping unwanted partitions *but* I don't see a way of using check constraint on *hashed partitions*

So this ugly example change make the query to work better
```ALTER TABLE users_p0 ADD CONSTRAINT  xx check ( id = '1' or id = '2' );
ALTER TABLE users_p2 ADD CONSTRAINT  xx check ( id <> '1' and id <> '2' );
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, it doesn't. It's not related to data type but current implementation of query planner. More details here: [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITION-PRUNING)

Comment: This is just a quick example to probe a deep problem. It doesn't matter that an id field type string is compared with another string with value "1"

Comment: If partition was by time, ```ALTER TABLE users_p0 CHECK ( date_field >= DATE '2006-03-01' AND date_field < DATE '2006-04-01' ))``` will fix the problem.
Cause partition is by hash, same kind of ```CHECK (id HASH MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0)``` is needed

Comment: I think if that `id` column was an `int` instead of a `varchar` then that would allow the check constraint to be put in place on each partition table e.g. `CHECK ( mod(id,3)=0)`. Something like that.

Comment: @TomMac I agree with you. ```ALTER TABLE users_p1 ADD CONSTRAINT u1_c check ( undocumented_hash_method(id) % 3 = 1);``` will be the way now. (in my case changing the id from varchar to number on 1Tb of data and lot of code is not a nice option ;)

Comment: This was fixed in [Postgres 12](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37e51a43f4ef66b6bc97d49f617b7591)

Answer (score 0):

About one of the comment which suggest to add a CONSTRAINT,
I would like to add and advice, maybe the hash used by PG isn't the mathematical modulus operator, be careful about that.

It is ok a id be on one partition, but I would double check the id mod 3 be on partition 0 for instance.

I had concrete cases where for a partitioned table on an integer field, the 1 don't go to the partition with modulus = 1

For me this notation is confusing, maybe is applied a module, but not a field value, but on the hash of a field value (It seems to me read about this somewhere)